# Android getSelectedItem, how to use?

Tags: java, android

Im trying use the spinner control result in order to point it to another screen that would be on the app. For example in the spinner control if the user chose chevy it would then take you to another screen which is coded in chevy.xml and Chevy.class. This is what i have thus far and need some help, as our book only used getSelectedItem and the example was only for an output statement.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Spinner;          

 public class Mainpage extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    String carChoice, chevy, ford, dodge, toyota;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  /*  carChoice = group.getSelectedItem().toString();
    }

     if (carChoice.compareTo(chevy)==0)
     {
     startActivity(new Intent(Mainpage.this, Chevy.class));
  */ }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        final Spinner group = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.carGroup);
        group.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         String selected = group.getItemAtPosition(1).toString();           
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
      long arg3)
```

arg2 is the index of selected item, arg3 is id of selected item. You may call getItem() method to get selected item object.

Comment: 0 is the first index. "if (arg2=0)" makes no sense, you should use "==".

Comment: Can I do- if(arg2 == 0) , in order to do something if the first item in the list is selected?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just based on your design.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SpinnerExample extends Activity
       {
                Spinner sp;
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
                String numbers[] = { "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX", "SEVEN",
                                                "EIGHT", "NINE", "TEN" };

                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
                      {

                                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                                setContentView(R.layout.main);

                                sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

                                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                                                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, numbers);
                                sp.setAdapter(adapter);

        sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3)                                                    
                    {
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), sp.getSelectedItem().toString(),
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                                                 
                        }
                 public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
                    {
                      // TODO Auto-generated method stub                 
                    }
       });
     }
}
```

> sp.getSelectedItem().toString() get item save  here

Answer (score 0):

Please see below code for complete example for spinner in Android.

```
public class ArrayAdapterDemo2 extends Activity implements
        AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    TextView selection;
    String[] items = { "Dipak", "Keshariya", "Software", "Deepak", 
            "Android Example", "Android Book",
            "Android", "i-phone", "Developer", "Tutorial" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        selection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selection);

        Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
                items);

        aa.setDropDownViewResource(
           android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spin.setAdapter(aa);
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
            long id) {
        // Here Position is Item Index
        selection.setText(spin.getSelectedItem().toString());
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        selection.setText("");
    }
}
```

And see below link for more information.

[Android Spinners](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)